# Bing image search APIs give different result that Bing Image web search page

Tags: bing, bing-api

I am using the bing image search APIs (endpoint: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search). Using this endpoint the results are different than what I am seeing on the bing image search website (https://www.bing.com/images/).

Do we know how I can get the same results using the APIs and the bing search website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected as bing.com consumes a lot of other information (with user's permission) such as session id, browser, form factor, etc. In API, all this info is optional and hence response may vary. Ideally, you can get very close to results on bing.com/images/ but replicating exactly is difficult.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, Can you give me an example how I can come close to the results from bing.com/images?

Comment: You can use client id, client ip, and location parameters described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-web-api-v7-reference.